# WMS layer not displaying in cesium globe

Tags: geoserver, wms, cesium, 3d-map

Im downloaded cesium 1.23 library from cesium site and added geoserver wms layer on the cesium globe, but its not displaying.

my query has mentioned below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Hello World!</title>
  <script src="Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
  <style>
  @import url(Cesium/widgets.css);

  #cesiumContainer {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: sans-serif;
  }

  body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
  }


</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
  <script>

var widget = new Cesium.CesiumWidget('cesiumContainer');

var url='http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms'; 
var layers = widget.scene.globe.imageryLayers;
    layers.removeAll();
    layers.addImageryProvider(new Cesium.WebMapServiceImageryProvider({
        url : url,        
        layers: 'layer_name'
    }));

Sandcastle.finishedLoading();

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to add wms layer over the cesium globe?

Comment: What error you are getting in your web console while running this page?

Comment: geoserver layer cannot be visible, firebug error mentioned below.


GET http://localhost:8181/test/Build/Cesium/Assets/IAU2006_XYS/IAU2006_XYS_15.json
 
200 OK
  2ms 
Cesium.js (line 426)
Error: WebGL: texImage2D: Uploading ArrayBuffers with FLIP_Y or PREMULTIPLY_ALPHA is slow.
 

...K_FLIP_Y_WEBGL,g),i(u.arrayBufferView)?_.texImage2D(y,0,m,a,l,0,d,p,u.arrayBuffe...

 
Cesium.js (line 441, col 24322)
An error occurred in "p": Failed to obtain image tile X: 0 Y: 0 Level: 0.
Cesium.js (line 429)
An error occurred in "p": Failed to obtain image tile X: 1 Y: 0 Level: 0.

Comment: I have tested your code in Cesium 1.6 version. It is running fine. I just need to change the port number of my geoserver and the layer name of WMS. I got the same error when I used layer an invalid layer name... Just check. All the best.